Did Patriot missiles miss Scuds at every shot in the 1st Gulf War?
YNet:

The last incident was during the First Gulf War in 1991 when the U.S. deployed Patriot batteries in Israel to persuade it not to retaliate against Iraq after Saddam Hussein launched over 40 missiles at Israel.
Those were older Patriot systems, which failed to intercept a single ballistic missile but did cause damage and injuries when one landed on a home in Ramat Gan.

LA Times:

The sophisticated ground-based antimissile system rocketed to prominence in the 1991 Gulf War, gaining the nickname “Scudbuster” as it seemed to obliterate Iraqi long-range ballistic missiles heading for Tel Aviv and Riyadh. But after the war, congressional and independent analyses concluded that the Patriot may actually have missed every Scud it targeted.

How true is this, given the politicking that sometimes goes into congressional hearings etc.?
FWTW, slightly more googling finds the opposite opinion from a lobby group:

January 18th, 1991 – U.S. Army Patriot operators successfully intercepted and destroyed an Iraqi SS-1C SCUD B in Saudi Arabia. This intercept was momentous as it was the first successful engagement by an Air Defense system ever in combat history.  Many successful engagements of Iraqi SS-1C SCUDs followed, leaving no doubt to the efficacy of Patriot as a ballistic missile defense system.


Technically your final quote need not be in contradiction to the other two. They could have had a single success in Saudi Arabia, hence tried it again in Israel, failed there and after some more fiddling and fine tuning got to a point where there where many more successful engagements. I have no idea whether this theory is true though.

The first casualty of war is the truth. Ukraine (and the USA) were boasting about how the Patriot batteries have downed a Khinzal hypersonic missile, yet the battery had to be retired for repairs - so, not that successful interception. Similarly Israel (and the USA) boasted about the effectivity of their anti-ballistic missile system against the last strike by Iran, but satellite images show dozens of impacts on israeli targets. During the war, official propaganda was that Patriots intercepted 100% of Scuds. After the war, it was revealed it was actually 0%.

@Rekesoft That seems like an answer, not a comment. Moreover, that a battery took out a hypersonic missile is not inconsistent with it having to be retired for repairs, for unrelated reasons, or reasons related to the use of the battery, or due to shrapnel from high speed disassembly of a hypersonic object (which is still a successful shootdown).

IIRC one of the issues is "miss". A Patriot doesn't have to physically impact the target, it's more like a grenade than a bullet. Nor does it have to destroy the target, just knock it off course; a "mission kill". But when the enemy is bombarding a broad civilian area a mission kill is not sufficient.

I’m voting to close this question because the Patriot Wikipedia page covers this well in Operational History, and I don't think we'll add to that.

@Schwern: does it? The section about "Persian Gulf War (1991) -- Success rate vs. accuracy" consists mostly of unsourced statements/paras.

@Schwern: true though, at the end of that section there is an actual quote from the Congressional thing: "There is little evidence to prove that the Patriot hit more than a few Scud missiles launched by Iraq during the Gulf War, and there are some doubts about even these engagements." How do we know that is an unbiased statement though?

I thought the Patriot missile "clock bug" has become a well known software failure that meant any Patriot missile that had been switched on for a while would miss its target. Here's a site that explains the bug and quotes the report from the "General Accounting office" https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/patriot.html

IIRC , the chopping bug is used as an example in the book "Elementary numerical analysis with Mathematica", by Keel & Keiper (1995)
